# Merge row in power query

Tags: merge, rows, powerquery

I am difficulties when it comes to merging 2 rows in power query based on same criteria  under one column.

So i have Col A, Col B and Col C
if Col A have a duplicated rows, Col B & Col C will be merge. Any workaround for this or is it just limitation in power query?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the new column created by the merge step by clicking on the button with the two arrows in the column header. From there you can get back the values for columns B and C.